# Mono Linq to XML throwing SIGSEGV

Tags: c#, mono, linq-to-xml, monodevelop

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one and I'm hoping that somebody can be kind enough give some advice about what might be going wrong with the code below.

I've got a project that I'm developing with Mono 3.0.7 in MonoDevelop 4.0.9 on Linux and the project is targeting .NET 3.5.

I need to process an XML file so I want to use Linq to XML to make it easier to work with the XML file.  I'm not having any problems generating the XML and writing it out to a file.  However, when I try to read things from the file, Mono is crashing with a SIGSEGV error.

For example, I'd like to try something like this:

```
//Load the document
XDocument indexFile = XDocument.Load(indexFilePath);

foreach (XElement acctElement in indexFile.Descendants("Account"))
{
    AcctCls acct = new AcctCls(acctElement.Attribute("AcctID").Value);
    AcctsList.Add(acct);

    foreach (XElement regionElement in acctElement.Descendants("Region"))
    {
        RegionCls region = new RegionCls(regionElement.Attribute("Region").Value);
        acct.RegionsList.Add(region);
    }
}
```

I have tried running this with the .NET Framework and it seems to run fine.  However, when I run this with Mono, I get the following error message:

```
    Stacktrace:
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      ...My own libraries...
      at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

    Native stacktrace:

        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4ae331]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x503b8b]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4226b2]
        /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xf830) [0x7f4f68629830]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d00d9]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d5049]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d5741]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d583f]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d67b5]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4d75fc]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4caeea]
        /usr/bin/mono() [0x4cb03e]

    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

I even get the same error when I do something as simple as this:

```
    IEnumerable acctsList = indexFile.Descendants("Account");

    foreach(XElement acctElmnt in acctsList)
    {
        string test = acctElmnt.Attribute("AcctID").Value;
    }
```

I've tried putting the XMLReader in a using statement and passing that XMLReader to the XDocument.Load method but that doesn't help either.  I don't know if this is relevant or not, but this is happening while I'm debugging the code and stepping through it.

I've been Googling for a few hours now and racking my brains trying everything, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.  The Mono website says that it supports all of Linq to XML and other people on various forums and sites that I'm reading seem to have this working fine so I'm wondering what it is that I'm missing.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you upload complete runnable code somewhere so we can test if it's a bug in mono, or a problem on your end?

Comment: @Jester Thanks for taking a look at this.  I put a small sample project up in a public bitbucket repository.  Here's the URL:  https://greyseal96@bitbucket.org/greyseal96/monolinqtoxmlbug.git  Let me know if you can't get it or if I should upload it somewhere else.  This was created and run in MonoDevelop 4.0.9.  I'm encountering the issue when I'm running in debugging mode and stepping through the code.  I set some breakpoints and I'm pretty sure that I included the breakpoint file with the rest of the code.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have MD 4.1.7 w/ mono 3.0.8 and your project seems to work fine here, both in MD and from the command line.

Comment: @Jester - Thanks.  That's an interesting bit of information.  Since those are still beta versions they're not in my distro's repos yet.  I'm going to have to compile from source and check that out, but that's gonna take some time.  I'll report back my results.  Do you know, offhand, if this was a reported bug that got fixed between mono 3.0.7 and 3.0.8?  I'm figuring that it's a mono thing because I can't see MD being responsible for messing that up.

Comment: It would be a highly unlikely coincidence if this was just fixed between our two revisions but I haven't checked.

Comment: @Jester - I downloaded the source for Mono 3.0.11 and MonoDevelop 4.1.9-6 and made packages for my distro so that I could upgrade my Mono and MonoDevelop installations.  I'm still getting the problem with these new versions.  Do you have any suggestions for what I should try next to get this resolved?  Is this something distro specific?

Comment: @Jester - Just as a quick follow-up, I also thought that I'd try installing the monodevelop-debugger-gdb to see if it could give me any more information and it did.  This is my first time using it so forgive my ignorance, but after a section about auto-loading being declined, I got some warnings that said the following:
`warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.`
`Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?`

Comment: ...continued... The rest of the stack trace was more information than would fit in a comment window so I took a screenshot of the stack trace and put it in the root directory of the test project that I uploaded to bitbucket.  I cut down the output to what looked like the relelvant info.  This missing part from the very top of the stack trace was pretty much the same as the error that I posted above as well as some warning about auto-trace not being enabled in gdb.  The bottom portion was likewise the same notice about the SIGSEGV error that is shown above.

Comment: ...continued... Also, I tried running this without debugging and it seems like it works without debugging.  From the stack trace output, it looks to me like the problem is only occurring while debugging because some symbols can't be loaded OR, it looks like it might also be something to do with multiple libpthread.so.0 objects working at the same time on different threads and possibly having some contention.  I can't be sure though.  Can you see any problems in the stack trace that jump out at you?  Thanks so much, once again, for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with this issue for a while, I finally figured out that the problem had to do with trying to debug the LINQ to XML statement.  Specifically, this seems to happen every time I try to step into a LINQ to XML statement.  If I don't step into the statement, and when I run the application normally without debugging, LINQ to XML works fine.  I think that the problem probably has to do with the inability to load the symbols as mentioned in my comments above.